# Using xpath to extract date

Tags: python, regex, xpath, python-requests, lxml

I'm trying to extract the date from a webpage, '07/18/16' in the comment below. I'm not clear on the syntax for xpath, how would you grab just the date?

```
#<p>Opened <a class="timeline" href="/trac3/timeline?from=2016-07-    
#18T14%3A46%3A43-04%3A00&amp;precision=second" title="See timeline at   
#07/18/16 14:46:43">6 weeks ago</a></p>

from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get(webpage)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

openDate = tree.xpath('//Opened/text()')

print 'Open Date: ', openDate
```

Comment: rsplit the title once on # then extract the second element and just split again taking the first element, use /a/@title in place of the text call to get the title

Comment: Actually *Opened* is text inside the p so your xpath finds nothing at all

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
import re
from lxml import html

data = """<p>Opened <a class="timeline" href="/trac3/timeline?from=2016-07-18T14%3A46%3A43-04%3A00&amp;precision=second" title="See timeline at 07/18/16 14:46:43">6 weeks ago</a></p>"""

tree = html.fromstring(data)
try:
    href = tree.xpath("//a[@class='timeline']/@href")[0]
    openDate = re.search(r'from=(\d+-\d+-\d+)', href).group(1)
    print('Open Date: ', openDate)
    # Open Date:  2016-07-18
except:
    print("Something went wrong")
```

This grabs the `@href` attribute first, then analyzes it with a regular expression.

---

Having read the question again, you might rather look for the **title attribute**:

```
try:
    href = tree.xpath("//a[@class='timeline']/@title")[0]
    openDate = re.search(r'\d+/\d+/\d+', href).group(0)
    print('Open Date: ', openDate)
    # Open Date:  07/18/16
except:
    print("Something went wrong")
```

Comment: My only guess would be that the OP wanted "07/18/16" (@title) and not "2016-07-18" (@href). Not worthy of a downvote in my opinion. The concept is still there +1.

Comment: @DanielHaley: Thanks, have updated the answer to reflect the title attribute as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way only using xpath 1.0:

```
substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(//a[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' timeline ')]/@title),'See timeline at '), ' ')
```

The `contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' timeline ')` might seem like overkill, but will account for the possibility of classes other than "timeline" being in the class attribute.

XPath test: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/7805b0601b1468ea17209127e14fa470

**lxml Example**

```py
from lxml import html

page = """<p>Opened <a class="timeline" href="/trac3/timeline?from=2016-07-18T14%3A46%3A43-04%3A00&amp;precision=second" title="See timeline at 07/18/16 14:46:43">6 weeks ago</a></p>"""
tree = html.fromstring(page)

try:
    openDate = tree.xpath("substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(//a[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' timeline ')]/@title),'See timeline at '), ' ')")
    print 'Open Date: ', openDate
    #Open Date: 07/18/16
except:
    print("Something went wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath works by matching elements in an XML structured document.

Your XPath will fail, because what you are saying is search the entire document ("//") for any elements called "Opened" (i.e. `<Opened/>`) and return their inner text ("text()").

Assuming your HTML is consistent, what you actually want to do is scrape the contents of the anchor titles for the date, something like this:

```
//p[contains(text(),'Opened')]/a[@class='timeline']/@title
```

this will search the entire document for any anchors which are of the class 'timeline' and that are within paragraphs containing the word 'Opened' and return the contents of their 'title' attributes.

Notice I said "any anchors"; you're result will be a list of matched titles, so you'll need to decide what to do if you have multiple matches.

Once you have the title(s), you'll need to do some string slicing in python to retrieve the date part.

I'm assuming it's just XPath you're struggling with so I have left out any python examples. I recommend this site as a great starting point for XPath: http://dh.obdurodon.org/introduction-xpath.xhtml

Answer (score -2):

You cant do this. Xpath directly choose tag, not fields in it.
So "//p/a[text()]" return all `<a class="timeline" href="/trac3/timeline?from=2016-07-18T14%3A46%3A43-04%3A00&amp;precision=second" title="See timeline at 07/18/16 14:46:43">6 weeks ago</a>`
Or you can choose by condition like "//p/a[text() = "6 weeks ago"]"
So get this `<a></a>` tag and then parse it with python

Comment: Are you saying xpath can't select attributes?